# Group by with two arguments. Grouping by metric - items that are "close"

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in ruby to group an array by using specified metric (not euclidian)? I know there is method `Enumerable#group_by`. Unfortunately I can only give it one argument. I would like it to group items using something like:

```
items.group_by do |x,y|
  some_metric(x,y) < 1.23       # the two items are 'close'
end
```

How to tackle something like this?

lets say I have items:

```
[['a', 'b'], 
 ['c', 'd'], 
 ['e','f'], 
 ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
 ['c', 'd', 'z'],
 ['a', 'b', 'k']]
```

And I have a metric that tells me how two arrays are the same. The `['a','b']` and `['a', 'b', 'c']` arrays should be much more closer than `['a', 'b']` and `['e', 'f']`.
So the ideal output would be something like:

```
[
  [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'k'],
  [['c', 'd'], ['c', 'd', 'z']],
  [['e','f']]
]
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of input/some_metric/output? It's unclear exactly what behavior you're asking for.

Comment: Suppose `items = [1,2,3]`. How do you want that grouped when using the metric in your example? ("sth" is for texting, not for SO).

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I have provided input / output. But right now as I think more on... I think I jumped the gun because I doubt there is a one-liner solution. I would need to tell ruby somehow what is the key to compare to. In my case it could be just any element. Then take and remove all the items that matches in collection, then loop again. Take one element -> all items that matches and so on...

Comment: Nicky, my point is that there is no solution for an arbitrary receiver (`items`) and metric.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this boils down to a problem called "clustering". See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: @user12341234 Good guess! I wanted to cluster ngrams in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do that by passing a block to `group_by`.

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4],[2,2],[6,8]]
arr.group_by{|f,s| f%2==0 && s%2==0}
```

Here arr is an array of tuples of numbers. Using group_by we check each tuple to see if both numbers are even. You could also pass a function.

```
arr.group_by{|f,s| some_function(f,s)}
```

A more specific example mught be:

```
def proximity(arr)
  alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
  dis_arr = []
  arr.each_with_index do |e,i|
    if i+1 < arr.length
      dis =  alpha.find_index(e) - alpha.find_index(arr[i+1])
      dis_arr << dis.abs
    end
  end
  dis_arr.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / arr.size
end

test = 
 [['a', 'b'], 
  ['c', 'd'], 
  ['e','f'], 
  ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
  ['c', 'd', 'z'],
  ['a', 'b', 'k']]

test.group_by{|arr| proximity(arr)}
```

Which returns:

```
{ 0.5 => [ 
    ["a","b" ],["c","d"],["e","f"]
  ],
  0.6666666666666666 => [
    [ "a","b","c"]],
  7.666666666666667 => [
    ["c","d","z"]
  ],
  3.3333333333333335 => [
    ["a","b","k"]
  ]
}
```

Which isn't exactly what you wanted, but `.group_by` returns a hash. It isn't too hard to convert that to an array to suit your needs.